# Using readr to read TSV where some fields have quotes. After writing back out, there is an extra set of quotes

Tags: r, csv, stringr, readr

I have a TSV where one of the fields is a string representation of an array, it looks something like this:

```
A    B
1    ["hello", "to", "you"]
2    ["some"]
3    ["stuff", "blah"]
```

I'm trying to read it in using `readr`

```
library(readr)
df = read_tsv('file.tsv', quote = '\"')
```

Then I'm writing it out using `write_tsv(df, 'out.tsv')`

The problem is that when I open `out.tsv` the result is the follow:

```
A    B
1    "[""hello"", ""to"", ""you""]"
2    "[""some""]"
3    "[""stuff"", ""blah""]"
```

In reading the file in I have tried `quote = ''`, `quote = '\"'` and `quote = '\\"'` in read_csv.  write_csv doesn't have a quote parameter so I can't set anything there.  How do I read in this file and write it back out so that the extra set of quotes don't get written out?

Comment: I realize that I can use base r `write.table(A, 'out.tsv', sep = '\t', quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)` but I'm wondering if there's a tidyverse way of accomplishing this

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue - I've filed it as an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/854) - hopefully there's a simple fix

Comment: Have you tried setting the option `quote_escape="none"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write_csv` now has the the `escape` argument (`quote_escape` has been deprecated). `escape` can take one of three options:

> - "double" - quotes are escaped by doubling them.
> - "backslash" - quotes are escaped by a preceding backslash.
> - "none" - quotes are not escaped.

For more information, [read the documentation.](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/write_delim.html)